# Find out the IP Address of an Industrial machine controller

Tags: ip

I have an industrial machine controller with an ethernet connection. the Controller is DTU-1000x for a Testing Machine.

I need to check the whether the controller has an inbuilt webserver based configuration tool .

I wonder how do I findout the IP address of this controller, so I can configure the IP of my adapter to one on the same subnet and try to see if there is a webserver on this.

Dont' have or can't get the usermanual of this thing.

I have tried the usual suspects 192.168.1.x etc but so far no luck.

I am on machine with windows 7

Answer (score 4):

I would start by connecting my machine to the same VLAN (or back to back) and running Wireshark to see if the device is attempting to communicate with anything else, reboot the device too to see if there is any initial communications that might reveal an IP address.

Then you can use nmap to port scan the device to see what services are running.

Failing that, a quick bit of Googling turns up the Korean manufacturer of the product: http://www.idtnt.com/eng/

And their contact email: dtnt@paran.com

You could always try asking for a manual

Answer (score 1):

If you physically have access to the device and assuming you are the network admin, you can trace down where it is connected. Find out which switch it's connected in. If you have access to the switch, like chintu said, connect your laptop to the same vlan and fire up wireshark. Good old console cable would provide access to the switch in worst case. You could've previously check for the mac address on the device physically if possible.

Assuming the device would be dhcp, you could make sure a dhcp server is configured for the said vlan. If not, hook the device in the same vlan as other machines. Once it gets an IP, you will be able to configure it via the web interface. Depending it's hirschmann or Schneider, usually they are dhcp at the beginning.

Those devices weither it's NOE card or PLC sometimes runs under 57600 baud rate. You can try to telnet directly in those with a rs232-usb cable.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

A switch or computer on the same LAN/VLAN should receive ARP announcements from the device. Find out its MAC address and look for it in the switch or computer ARP table.